# Pygame: Efficient way to call draw function in for loops

Tags: python, numpy, pygame

Here's my problem, I want to draw a grid with pygame so I have this loop in which self.data changes at every time step

```
    def draw(self, surface):
        for a in range(self.height):
            for b in range(self.width):
                if self.data[a * self.width + b]:
                    pygame.draw.rect(surface, CELL_COLOR,
                                 pygame.Rect(b * CELL_WIDTH, a * CELL_HEIGHT, CELL_WIDTH, CELL_HEIGHT))
```

But this function is called at every time step of my program (ideally 60 times a second) and it really bothers me to have a 'python' for loop in it (it uses 70% of the CPU time)

Is there a more efficient way to do that?

I usually use numpy to speed up such functions but the call to a draw function really bothers me

Comment: Is it the same grid every time? Create a separate surface just for the grid, draw to it once and then just blit the entire grid in one call every step instead?

Comment: Please read [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). You must paste the code in the question.

Comment: Creating a new rect every frame seems me really inefficient. I would save your grid as different rects, each covering one of the tiles of the grid.

Comment: I edited the question, the grid changes, thank you @IainShelvington

Comment: Thanks @The_spider, I made this change which saved me 1~2 fps already